# looping through properties in struct - C

Tags: c, properties, struct, for-loop

Can I use a forloop to get the property names of a "struct" in C? Or would I just have make a separate list? (Just the name I am looking for)

Comment: The member identifiers are for the human and compiler, the output really doesn't care about the name, just it's offset in the `struct`. Therefore, it ditches that information (i.e., C has no reflection.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How do you want to handle different types? Some pseudo-code might help to give alternative suggestions.

Comment: I am working with function pointers and wondered if I could have just cut down on needing a second list of names. So I could just loop the list and compare it to a word to get the right callbacks.

Comment: For starters you could put structs in the list that contain both the name and the function pointer - or better use some existing dictionary solution to get name-to-function-pointer resolution. Also macros could reduce the work of defining these lists/dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to make a separate list. The C programming language doesn't have any introspection capabilities that would let you enumerate the property names of a struct.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops do not have the ability to enumerate `struct` members in C, no. In fact, once compiled, a C program really doesn't have any concept of the member names at all, it just uses offsets from the struct pointer.